# An error with the LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
if(!empty($count)){
  $BattingQuery->where('countries_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$count.'%');
}
```

I am running this query but this yield a problem, if I run a search on country id `11, 12, 13, 14;` I always get the `country_id` of `1` aswell as `11` for example. How do I make it an Equals? as both '=' and Equals return nothing and break the query.

Answer (score 1):

The query builder has some very useful [where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses).

```
$count = 13;
if(!empty($count)){
  $BattingQuery->where('countries_id', $count);
}
```

This will return all your models with a `countries_id` equal to `13`

Comment: Thats not what i want. I want the query to come back with the exact id on what i have inputted. As at the moment with like it comes back with multiple id's  if a number is in the number your searching for.

Comment: You want an exact match? Something that would be done in php by `$a == $b`?

Comment: yes countries_id = '%'.$count.'%'. Count is an input select.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :

```
if(!empty($count)){
  $BattingQuery->orWhere('countries_id', 'like', '%' . $count . '%');
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!